# Connect derby DB to Java

Tags: java, sql, database, intellij-idea, derby

I wanted to connect DB to Java application in Intellij.
I set the classpath correctly, so that javac from cmd is working correct.
I have also downloaded all the jar files needed as a libary, but I still get `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby`

What can be the problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    } catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true;user=user;password=pass";

    try (
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "user", "pass");
    )
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlException)
    {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try if `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` works. And it seems your connection url is wrong.

```
    final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB;create=true;user=user;password=pass";
    Connection connection = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL ); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I tried that one, but instead got Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.

Comment: so check the port, username and password.